# How to hit Vscode breakpoints in unit tests from within a docker-compose setup running Django

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

What I'm trying to do seems simple enough, but it's been crazy hard to actually get there. I have a Django application that runs in a docker-compose environment, and I want to run and debug the unit tests with breakpoints in Vscode.

Since this is a big project with a team that doesn't necessarily use vscode, I can't add libraries willy-nilly (like ptvsd, for example). I'm hoping there's a magic configuration for `tasks.json` and `launch.json` that will makes things work.

I have a container for a postgres database, one for django, and one for redis, all defined in docker-compose.yml. There's a command that I can run in the terminal that will run the tests, it's:

```
docker-compose run --rm app python manage.py test
```

where `app` is the django app container. I'd love to be able to run this command in such a way that it can hit breakpoints in vscode.

My incomplete stab at the `launch.json` file looks like this:

```json
{
  "configurations": [{
    "name": "Docker: Python - Django",
    "type": "docker",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "compose-for-debug",
    "python": {
      "pathMappings": [{
        "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "remoteRoot": "/app"
      }],
      "projectType": "django"
    }
  }]
}
```

And my `tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [{
      "type": "docker-build",
      "label": "docker-build",
      "platform": "python",
      "dockerBuild": {
        "tag": "dockerdebugging:latest",
        "dockerfile": "${workspaceFolder}/Dockerfile",
        "context": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "pull": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "docker-run",
      "label": "docker-run: debug",
      "dependsOn": [
        "docker-build"
      ],
      "python": {
        "args": [
          "test",
          "--nothreading",
          "--noreload"
        ],
        "file": "manage.py"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think I need to convert the build task to a docker compose task somehow, but I just can't figure out how its done. It may also make sense to run the containers in the terminal, and somehow make vscode attach to them with breakpoints enabled.

Even some help with how to approach this would be great. I know it's a tricky one.

Comment: Just a note: In the end I couldn't figure this out so I took a different approach. You can install the extension "Remote Containers", and open VsCode inside the docker container. Then just use launch.json as normal and the breakpoints should work.

Answer (score 2):

This question became somewhat popular, but a direct answer never came. If you've landed here looking for a way to hit breakpoints inside vscode using docker, my suggestion is to use the `Remote Container` extension.

When the container is up, right click it and open a vscode window inside of the container itself. Then everything will just work.